# Inverse Kinematics Knee

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

I'm out of options, I have to ask... Why is the knee in the below picture not always pointing to the ik.knee.l bone?

I've read [this](https://medium.com/unity3danimation/overview-of-inverse-kinematics-9769a43ba956) (VERY informative) and I also followed [this](https://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-basic-low-poly-character-rig-in-blender--cg-16955) tutorial... But no luck. I'd appreciate any help/insight into this. Because I have a whole lot of problems with ik in general, and hoping the answers will fix other problems I've run into, namely the hand and finger bones.. lol One problem at a time though.

[image: Knee Problems]

I was under the impression that the way IK works, is if you move the leg ik bone at the foot, it would move the chain correctly, do I need to add another pole somewhere to keep the knee from bending the wrong way? The way the kneecap would.

The blender file can be found (Updated) here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DKorMRirof7BCtw3VI2uHUaKg1PXESyl

I attempted to add another ik.bone/target on the thigh, but that didn't work.

Comment: there's no more constraint in the armature you share, maybe it looses them during the import? maybe share a blend file?

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed the file. I thought I had added the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to bend the knees a bit in *Edit* mode so that it knows in what direction it is supposed to bend in *Pose* mode

[image]

Comment: Oh man, that was way to easy. Thank you. I think I get more of how IK works now. Appreciate it.

Comment: Yes that's the kind of little things you must not forget when you create the armature  ;)